# Electric field due to a time varying Magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

I am recently working with faradays law, and learned that that a time varying magnetic field can cause a Electric field as
$$
\nabla \times \vec{\textbf{E}} = -\frac{\partial \vec{\textbf{B}}}{\partial t}
$$
now, I was working with induced electric fields and we derived that in a region of Circular magnetic field the Induced Electric field is given by
$$
\vec{\textbf{E}}=\frac{r}{2}\frac{\partial \vec{\textbf{B}}}{\partial t}
$$
Which comes out of the integral form of faraday law.
In the book which I was studying it was said that in the case of circular field  the electric field is circular. But when I tried to prove it using Diffrential form of faraday's law , I got stuck in equations.
Here is what I did:
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{\textbf{E}}=0
$$
and, Here I am assuming that there is a right-handed coordinate system and the magnetic field is changing only in the $z$ direction (Any way the field can change.)
$$
\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial y}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial x}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial t}
$$
Now I am not able to proceed further.
I hope that you will help me with my problem.

Comment: Is your book talking about the field distribution in long solenoids of circular cross section? That the magnetic field inside such a  solenoid is constant and that it disappears on the outside is an approximation, even if it is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work in cylindrical coordinates. By symmetry, $\vec E$ only has a $\hat{\phi}$ component that satisfies

$$(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec E)_z = \frac 1 {\rho}
\frac{\partial(\rho E_{\phi})}{\partial\rho}=-\dot{\vec{B}}$$

with a divergence satisfying:

$$\nabla\cdot \vec E = \frac 1 {\rho} \frac{\partial E_{\phi}}{\partial \phi} = 0 $$

(which means $E_{\phi}$ is constant, at fixed $\rho$). Plug that into the curl and you get an answer (without a 2 in it).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I was just an idiot that I was trying to solve in cartesian.